# Outbound Messages, Apex Callouts or Polling

Tags: apex, webservices, callout, workflowoutboundmessage

We need certain events in SalesForce to trigger our web service endpoints being hit (to kick off internal processes). As I understand it, there are 3 options here:

- Outbound Messages
- Apex Callouts
- Polling

Outbound Messages have very few limits, but WSDL-driven code generation for our web services.

Apex Callouts seem wonderful, but are extremely limited with how often we can execute them.

Polling allows us to write our own custom software, but has the drawback of not being reactive or event-driven.

I was hoping a well-seasoned, battle-worn SF veteran might be able to speak to the pros/cons of each approach, perhaps recommend any others (if they exist), and perhaps outline a rubric to use for making this decision.

Comment: take a look at dreamforce 13 aync apex design patterns at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY for a wonderful solution by Dan Appleman that eliminates most async (i.e. callout) restrictions if your application can be designed for async behavior

Comment: Thanks @crop1645 - do you know off-hand if Async Apex can be made fault tolerant? For instance with Outbound Messages there is a queuing mechanism that will keep retrying to send messages for 24 hours. My understanding is that Apex Callouts don't support this "retry"; but can Async Apex accomplish this?

Comment: yes because the framework, once you go through it, essentially uses an sobject to define async requests; if a request fails, then the sobject is not marked as completed and will be retried;